# Java. IO. Object I/O Stream Помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: java, сокет, io

У меня должен передаваться `String[]` через сокет из `ObjectOutputStrem` в `ObjectInputStrem` но падает с ошибкой:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.net.SocketInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectInputStream

Почему не кастуется не понятно... помогите пожалуйста

Вот клиент:

```
private void startClient() {
    this.socketAccept();

    try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream()) {

        String[] inSocket = {"abc", "mvd"};

        this.getList((ObjectOutputStream) out, inSocket);

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getList(ObjectOutputStream out, String[] list) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(list);
    }
```

Вот сервер он получает:

```
private void startServer() {
    this.initServerSocket();
    System.out.println("wait connection...");
    this.socketAccept();
    System.out.println("connection accept");


    try (InputStream in = this.socket.getInputStream()) {
        String[] res = this.getObj((ObjectInputStream) in);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String[] getObj(ObjectInputStream objIn) throws IOException {
    try {
        return (String[]) objIn.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создать ObjectInputStream из вашего InputStream in, который им не является

```
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
String[] res = this.getObj(oin);
```

Comment: Все получилось спасибо!